# AWS SAM recreates DynamoDB Table when adding SortKey or GlobalSecondaryIndex

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sam

I am using [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) to deploy a DynamoDB table and my template.yaml looks something like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

  DynamoDBTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: owner
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: owner
          KeyType: HASH
```

I do `sam build && sam deploy` to (re-)deploy it.
When I add a sortKey and/or a GlobalSecondaryIndex the yaml file looks something like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

  DynamoDBTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: owner
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: Timestamp
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: owner
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: Timestamp
          KeyType: RANGE
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: TestIndex
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: owner
              KeyType: HASH
            - AttributeName: Timestamp
              KeyType: RANGE
          Projection:
            ProjectionType: KEYS_ONLY
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-gsi.html) updating these fields should be possible (no interruption).
But in my case the deploy command always recreates the whole table (deleting all data).
Am I doing something wrong here?

### Edit

Maybe my explanation was a unclear about that. I tried to add both (GSI and sortKey) but I also tried adding each one by one, *i.e.* just adding the GSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDb tables key schema and LSI can only be set during table creation and only GSI can be added later.

Just to add on to it, We must add a name attribute in Sam/CloudFormation to the resources like Databases, Dynamo Tables, etc to avoid getting deleted. When a resource needs replacement, deploy will fail, rather than deleting and replacing it with a new resource.
Ex:

```
DynamoDBTable:
   Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
   Properties:
     TableName: "test-table"
     BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

Comment: `TableName` was the key. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Adding a sort key, or otherwise changing the KeySchema requires the table to be replaced.  See the correct [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html) for the table definition.

[image]

Adding/Changing an LSI also requires replacement.
Adding a GSI can be done without interruption.

Though I think changing a GSI KeySchema would require the GSI to be replaced also...the docs seem to imply that it doesn't.

Comment: As mentioned above. If I only add the GSI (not touching the KeySchema)  it will try to recreate the table.